# Is there a way to generate random number in mysql and append on a string?

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I want to write a query that generates a number 1 - 1000 and inserts it into an email address, where that email is an empty string. I know the syntax is off, but can MySQL generate a random number that I can insert into a string to create an email such as na@na122.com?

The update statement I'm looking for would be a query like this:

```
UPDATE contacts SET email = 'na@na' + random_number(1-1000) + '.com' WHERE email = '';
```

Comment: So this is where all the spam is coming from?  foo123@, foo345@, etc?

Answer (score 7):

I did this

```
 CONCAT("na@na", RAND() * 100 , '.com')
```

Comment: combine it with `ABS()` to get rid of the float... `CONCAT("na@na", ABS(RAND() * 100), '.com')`

Comment: thanks i noticed that was an issue and i used CONCAT("na@na", ROUND(RAND() * 10000)  , '.com')

Comment: I was using double concat, I did not know that I could put more than one string. Thanks for the answer !